# creating search widget with two input fields in android

Tags: android, searchview

My application has a requirement of implementing a search widget with two input fields 
1. For location (this field will have default value of current location)
2. for name of model in location

I have successfully integrated search widget in my app action bar. it by default it showing only one field.

Is there any way to create my own search widget that will have two fields as described above

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Edittext to get the text from user is not possible and you have to open up a new activity to get the input from the user as far as the widgets in android is concerned .

You can refer this tutorial on widgets to know the steps for creating remoteviews for your widgets layout : [Android Widgets Development](http://androidheap.com/Widgets-Tutorial-In-Android.php)